# Computing a parity check matrix given the minimum code distance

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

As per the title, I would like to know if it is possible to construct a parity check matrix given the length of the code, dimension and the minimum distance of the code. For example, if I would like to construct a parity matrix for this code C[22, 13, 5], how do I go about doing this?

Comment: _In general,_ the answer is No, you cannot construct a parity check matrix for a $[n,k,d]$ code even if you can prove that such a code must exist.

Comment: Find 22 binary vectors of length nine such that no four are linearly dependent. If you can. I don't know if it's possible. IOW - agree with Dilip.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in the comment by [Dilip Sarwate](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15941/dilip-sarwate).

From the comments:

"*In general*, the answer is No, you cannot construct a parity check matrix for a $[n,k,d]$ code even if you can prove that such a code must exist."